# Как передать ссылку на изображение в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, скрипт

У меня есть два скрипта первый это item в нем должна находится ссылка на изображение предмета public string sprite; 
И второй скрипт это инвентарь мне нужно передать ссылку сюда.
Item it = items[i];
img.GetComponent().sprite = Resources.Load(it.sprite);
Я задаю в инспеторе ссылку на спрайт в первом скрипте ссылка сохраняется все видно, а после того как я получаю ссылку во втором скрипте значение null.
А если ввести public string sprite = "IconImage/Grib"; то все работает, но я же не буду создавать для каждого предмета свой скрипт, подскажите плиз.

Comment: `Resources.Load(it.sprite) as Sprite` надо писать вроде....... к тому же кто такой `img`? Почему там написано просто `GetComponent()` а не например `GetComponent(SpriteRenderer)` ? Может поэтому и null ? Покажи весь код и скрины, пожалуй

Comment: GameObject img = Instantiate(conteiner); Лучше скажите почему у меня не сохраняется значение когда я изменяю его в инспекторе.

Comment: Я тебе подсказал в комментарии..... причем минимум два пункта указал....

Comment: Как тут скинуть скришот ?

Comment: Есть кнопка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/647050/edit) у вопроса. Добавь туда и код свой  и скрин